# Sharing a power pivot enabled Excel file with power pivot slicers with users who don't have power pivot

Tags: powerpivot

I have an Excel file that uses Power Pivot to produce several pivot tables with Power Pivot Slicers. I have shared the file with users who do not have power pivot installed, and they can see the pivot tables with no problem. However when they try to use the slicers to change the data in the pivot tables, they get a data source error. They are stuck with the initial choice on slicers and cannot view more data.

Is that how things will work for a user without Power Pivot installed?

Is there any way to enable the slicers without installing power pivot?

Comment: Are you using excel 2010/2013/2016, and what version are you using, and your users.

Comment: 2010. Everybody is using Excel 1010.

Comment: then this will be the behaviour. Since the model cannot be read, it's impossible to connect to the datasource. 
In Excel 2013/2016 the engine is always included, so it would work without installing the add-on. (Remark: to be able to edit the model, you need a specific excel license, so check before upgrading).